Check whether the vertices of a triangle are collinear
It's getting a bit complicated.
Unfortunately, our professor uses his own library. Maybe someone can still help me. It's generally about geometry and homogeneous coordinates. The task was to construct a circumcircle that passes through all vertices from a file that was read out. To do this, I calculated the center perpendicular and determined the intersection point. The drawing of the circumcircle was somehow not clear to me and so I first had it drawn to 31.5. Now the task is to see whether the points are collinear or not. I'll upload the file for reading in and the library here if anyone wants to test it.
where I get stuck is the line with #check whether the three vertices of the triangle are collinear
Feel free to ask if anything is unclear.
Best regards
zebat
import sys
import time
import math
import numpy as np
from enum import Enum
from libcfcg import cf

pointsV = [] # python representation of point vectors
cfPoints = [] # internal 2D representation with x and y
pointVectorsV = [] # internal pointVector representation with x, y, and w

def myEqualZero(value):  # if you expect 0 it's mostly a very small number but not 0!!!
    return abs(value) < 0.001

def mySign(value):  # difference to NumPy:  mySign(0)=1    !!!
    if value < 0:
        return -1
    return 1

def readPoints():
    dataV = cf.readDatFilePointVector("geometry_files/UMKREIS1.DAT")

    for i in range(0, dataV.size()):
        pV = dataV.get(i)
        pointsV.append([pV.getX(), pV.getY(), pV.getW()])

    for pV in range(0, len(pointsV)):
        if pointsV[pV][2] != 1:
            raise ValueError;
        cfPoints.append(cf.Point(pointsV[pV][0], pointsV[pV][1]))  # drawable points
        pointVectorsV.append(cf.PointVector(pointsV[pV][0], pointsV[pV][1])) # list of Point-Vectors

readPoints()

# part 1, create coordinatesystem & draw all points/lines
window = cf.WindowCoordinateSystem(600, cf.Interval(-10, 270), cf.Interval(-10, 270), "Coordinatesystem")
window.setWindowDisplayScale(1.0)
window.drawAxis(cf.Color.BLACK, 10, 10)

# Read points of the triangle
for pV in pointsV:
    print("Drawing point: ", pV)
    sys.stdout.flush() # force output
    time.sleep(0.1) # wait for console; increase if necessary
    window.drawPoint(cf.Point(pV[0], pV[1])) # default color is black
# Draw points of the triangle
for i in range(0, len(cfPoints)):
    p0 = cfPoints[i]
    p1 = cfPoints[(i+1) % len(cfPoints)] 
    window.drawLine(p0, p1)

window.show() # no display of drawings without this line!!!


Mittelpunkte = []
Punkte = []

#Determine and draw perpendiculars
print("Taste drücken, um Mittelsenkrechten einzuzeichnen")
sys.stdout.flush() # force output
time.sleep(0.1) # wait for console; increase if necessary
window.waitKey()
for pV in range(0,2):
    
    #Calculate the center point from two points
    MPV1 = pointVectorsV[pV].add(pointVectorsV[pV+1])
    MPV1.normalize()
    Mittelpunkte.append(MPV1)
    MP1 = cf.Point(MPV1)
    window.drawPoint(MP1)
    window.show()
    
    #Direction vector for G, PointV1 - MPV1
    RMPV1 = pointVectorsV[pV+1].sub(MPV1)
    
    #Calculate normal direction vector from direction vector
    NMPV1 = RMPV1.clone()
    NEWX = RMPV1.getY()*(-1)
    NEWY = RMPV1.getX()
    NMPV1.setX(NEWX)
    NMPV1.setY(NEWY)
    
    # Calculate X1 from H with r=3
    X1 = MPV1.add(NMPV1*3)
    Punkte.append(X1)
    XP1 = cf.Point(X1)
    window.drawPoint(XP1, cf.Color.BLUE)
    window.show()
    
    # Draw perpendiculars through X1 and X2
    window.drawLine(MP1, XP1, cf.Color.BLUE, cf.Window2D.LineType_DEFAULT, 1)
    window.show()
    

#Calculate and draw the intersection of the perpendiculars
print("Taste drücken, um den Schnittpunkt der Mittelsenkrechten einzuzeichnen")
sys.stdout.flush() # force output
time.sleep(0.1) # wait for console; increase if necessary
window.waitKey()

N1 = Mittelpunkte[0].crossProduct(Punkte[0])
N2 = Mittelpunkte[1].crossProduct(Punkte[1])
N1.normalize()
N2.normalize()
S = N1.crossProduct(N2)
S.normalize()
print("Test", S.getX(), S.getY(), S.getW())
SP1 = cf.Point(S)
window.drawPoint(SP1, cf.Color.RED)
window.show()


#Draw a circle around the center of the vertical and at the three corner points
print("Taste drücken, um den den Kreis der 3 Punktvektoren einzuzeichnen")
sys.stdout.flush() # force output
time.sleep(0.1) # wait for console; increase if necessary
window.waitKey()

window.drawCircle(SP1, 31.5, cf.Color.GREEN)
window.show()



#check whether the three vertices of the triangle are collinear
print("Taste drücken, um zu überprüfen ob die Punkte Kollinear sind")
sys.stdout.flush() # force output
time.sleep(0.1) # wait for console; increase if necessary
window.waitKey()



    
# end
print("Press any key to finish")
sys.stdout.flush() # force output
time.sleep(0.1) # wait for console; increase if necessary
window.waitKey()

window = None


Three points A,B,C lie on the same line if vector (cross) product of AB and AC vectors is zero (with some tolerance):
(C.X-A.X)*(B.Y-A.Y)-(C.Y-A.Y)*(B.X-A.X) == 0

